# Can I get index from each button?

Tags: javascript, button, indexing, dynamic

```
for(idx in addList)
        {
            row += '<tr>';
            row += '<td>'+addList[idx].name+'</td>';
            row += '<td>'+addList[idx].id+'</td>';
            row += '<td><a class="btn btn-danger" value="idx" href="javascript:deleteFromAddList(addList[idx].id)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash icon-white"></i> {=getLocaleString("delete")}</a></td>';
            row += '</tr>';
        }
        $('#addListRow').empty();
        $('#addListRow').append(row);
```

I want to know how I can get idx from each button?

Like this. idx just increased ex)0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9......

But I want to choose idx=0 when I clicked 0 idx button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I'll answer what you actually asked, then suggest what I believe to be a better approach.

You can use string concatenation in your handler string:

```
for (idx in addList) // <=== This is suspect, see below
{
    row += '<tr>';
    row += '<td>'+addList[idx].name+'</td>';
    row += '<td>'+addList[idx].id+'</td>';
    row += '<td><a class="btn btn-danger" href="javascript:deleteFromAddList(addList[' + idx + '].id)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash icon-white"></i> {=getLocaleString("delete")}</a></td>';
// −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^^^^^^^^^^^
    row += '</tr>';
}
$('#addListRow').empty();
$('#addListRow').append(row);
```

Although if doing it that way, I'd just provide the `id` unless you think it may change between when this is rendered and when the click occurs (this works for numeric IDs, which your code seemed to expect them to be):

```
for (idx in addList) // <=== This is suspect, see below
{
    row += '<tr>';
    row += '<td>'+addList[idx].name+'</td>';
    row += '<td>'+addList[idx].id+'</td>';
    row += '<td><a class="btn btn-danger" href="javascript:deleteFromAddList(' + addList[idx].id + ')"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash icon-white"></i> {=getLocaleString("delete")}</a></td>';
// −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    row += '</tr>';
}
$('#addListRow').empty();
$('#addListRow').append(row);
```

**Instead**, though, I'd use event delegation so you didn't hook up a handler at all. Perhaps the `href` could be `#delete-${id}` or similar for visual purposes:

```
for (idx in addList) // <=== This is suspect, see below
{
    row += '<tr>';
    row += '<td>'+addList[idx].name+'</td>';
    row += '<td>'+addList[idx].id+'</td>';
    row += '<td><a class="btn btn-danger" data-id="' + addList[idx].id + '" href="#delete-' + addList[idx].id + '"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash icon-white"></i> {=getLocaleString("delete")}</a></td>';
// −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    row += '</tr>';
}
$('#addListRow').empty();
$('#addListRow').append(row);
```

You'd hook up your event handler **once**, like this:

```
$('#addListRow').on("click", ".btn.btn-danger", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    deleteFroAddList($(this).attr("data-id"));
});
```

Live Example (with various other updates — looping the array using an array method, template literals, removing the `tr` for the clicked button, etc.):

```js
function deleteFromAddList(id) {
    id = Number(id);
    console.log(`Deleting ID ${id}`);
    addList = addList.filter(entry => entry.id !== id);
    console.log(`New list:`);
    console.log(addList);
}
$('#addListRow').on("click", ".btn.btn-danger", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    deleteFromAddList($(this).attr("data-id"));
    $(this).closest("tr").remove(); // <== To remove the `tr`
});

let addList = [
    {name: "First", id: 1},
    {name: "Second", id: 2},
    {name: "Third", id: 3},
    {name: "Fourth", id: 4},
    {name: "Fifth", id: 5},
];
let row = "<table><tbody>" +
    addList.map(entry =>
        `<tr>
            <td>${entry.name}</td>
            <td>${entry.id}</td>
            <td><a class="btn btn-danger" data-id="${entry.id}" href="#delete-${entry.id}"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash icon-white"></i> delete</a></td>
        </tr>`
    ).join("") +
    "</tbody></table>";
$('#addListRow').html(row); // This does .empty() + .append()
```

```html
<div id="addListRow"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

About `for (idx in addList)`: If `addList` is an array, I suggest using [one of the array iteration methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/for-each-over-an-array-in-javascript/9329476#9329476) rather than `for-in`, which is for enumerating object properties.

Comment: I want to delete value from array but You also can see there is no connection between index and button so when I click button , there is a bug that last index is deleted...

Comment: and I used array like this , var addList = new array();  If Array in javascript helps auto refresh for index in array.

Comment: For example , When I create 3 values in array , display as a list in view and delete click second button , if javascript supports this , third button index becomes 2... but I can't get changed index from button because button's index is static

Comment: finally I want to pass this array and assign this array to php

Comment: I tried your suggested answer. it works! but I just only delete Asc... If I have two in lists , I can't delete second in array before first in array is deleted

Comment: @EqualLove - This is why I suggested using `id` instead of `idx`, because the array changes between rendering and the event occuring. I've updated the answer with a live example of one approach you could take.

Comment: I tried all. but I also can't delete second before first is deleted....

Answer (score 0):

Generating HTML by building strings is a bad idea and doesn't allow the flexibility for what you are asking to do.

Rather, create real HTML elements and attach properties to them.

I don't use jQuery, so I'll include an example using standard JavaScript.

(Important note: Notice that I am using `let` for the value of `i`.  Using `var` will *not* work.)

```js
const btn_home = document.querySelector("#button-home");

for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  const label = document.createTextNode(`I am ${i}`);
  const btn = document.createElement("button");
  btn.appendChild(label);

  btn.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
    alert(`This is ${i}`);
  });

  btn_home.appendChild(btn);
}
```

```html
<div id="button-home"></div>
```